# Move file from internal storage to Sd card

Tags: android, sd-card, movefile

I want to move file from internal storage to sd card. I've tried with `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` but it's moving internal storage only.

I've used below code:

```
ContextCompat.getExternalFilesDirs(mActivity, null)[0]
```

but it's moving in package folder

```
/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.unzipdemo/files/MyFileStorage/SampleFile.txt
```

I want to move files in a specific folder name. Can you please help me to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this method `copyDirectoryOneLocationToAnotherLocation()`

> Pass the internal file value as source location and External file path
>   as target location

```
public static void copyDirectoryOneLocationToAnotherLocation(File sourceLocation, File
            targetLocation)
            throws IOException {

        if (sourceLocation.isDirectory()) {
            if (!targetLocation.exists()) {
                targetLocation.mkdir();
            }

            String[] children = sourceLocation.list();
            for (int i = 0; i < sourceLocation.listFiles().length; i++) {

                copyDirectoryOneLocationToAnotherLocation(new File(sourceLocation, children[i]),
                        new File(targetLocation, children[i]));
            }
        } else {

            InputStream in = new FileInputStream(sourceLocation);

            OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(targetLocation);

            // Copy the bits from instream to outstream
            byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
            int len;
            while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
                out.write(buf, 0, len);
            }
            in.close();
            out.close();
        }

    }
```

**NOTE** :- After copying delete the source file